# Specifying different "TAG" column name in Liquibase

Tags: amazon-redshift, liquibase

I'm trying to make use of the liquibase (v3.6.1) redshift lib (https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-redshift) to automate udpates to our redshift cluster and I'm running into an issue. When Liquibase tries to create the databasechangelog table for the first time it fails because the column name "TAG" is a reserved word in Redshift.

Now, I did find this thread (http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/redshift-support) which brings up the issue with the lib author. I am using the latest release (1.0) of the library, which while not that recent, has supposedly fixed this issue according to the lib author. However, it either isn't fixed, or alternatively because this is a column name internally used by Liquibase it doesn't do any checking against the library's reserved words list.

My question is this - is there a way to tell Liquibase to use a different name for the TAG column? If I could do that then I might be able to get around this issue.

Comment: So, weirdly, this is now working for me. I didn't change anything at all, but it seems like the failure while creating the TAG column during the initial run-through is no longer appearing. Just noting it here for anyone that comes across this post in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this column name is hard coded. You can customize the name of the two liquibase tables but not the columns inside

Comment: Thanks, I guess we'll have to forgo using Liquibase for this then.